# Sessions are automatically disconnecting on Oracle Server

Tags: oracle, session, rhel5

Though there are relevant questions on SO, I couldn't find any possible solution from those. I observe a lot of `ORA-00020:maximum number of processes (X) exceeded` errors that I see on my application logs and hence triggering false alerts.

***where X=200 on application*

There are no application related issues that I observe but there are the above mentioned errors. The application user is under the Oracle profile `APPUSER` with the resource limit parameters as below:

- `APPUSER IDLE_TIME UNLIMITED`
- `APPUSER CONNECT_TIME UNLIMITED`

Is there an ideal setting on the above two parameters that can resolve any such issue? Please help me understand if I'm totally off-road in resolving the errors and frequent DB session drops.

Adding to this, there is an additional topic where I got to know from a question posted on ORACLE forums that if the Paging space (RHEL 5.x) isn't allotted properly then the system might randomly kill sessions to free up resources.

Can anyone shed some light on this too? Appreciate if anyone can provide some pointers / suggestions that may lead to a possible solution on this!!!

Comment: Whats the output of `SQL> show parameter processes` I think its 200 according to the error message. You could increase the number processes by modifying PROCESSES initialization parameter. Also you better ask such question in dba.stackexchange.com. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams188.htm

Comment: Thanks for your input @JSapkota, I'll do so!

Comment: The error means that you hit the maximum amount of processes on the DB. Each session gets an associated session process on the server. You can configure that amount as a DB parameter. Right now the maximum is 200 so if your system needs more than 200 sessions you will have to increase that. Note, also background processes are included in this parameter, not only session processes.